# Horizontal gap between side-by-side tcolorbox environments

Tags: tcolorbox, pattern, horizontal, gap

I'm trying to create a modern layout for my CV using the `tcolorbox` package. Here's what I've accomplished so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperheight=842pt,
    paperwidth=595pt,
    margin=0pt,
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

%%%

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{theme}{HTML}{333d4f}
\definecolor{shader}{HTML}{e3e4e6}

%%%

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{sidebar}[1][]{
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=theme,
  sharp corners,
  width=0.35\paperwidth,
  height=#1,
  nobeforeafter,
  valign=center,
  halign=center,
}

\newtcolorbox{mainbox}[1][]{        
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,    
  sharp corners,
  width=0.65\paperwidth,
  height=#1,
  nobeforeafter,
  valign=center,
  halign=center,
}

\newtcolorbox{headbox}[1][]{    
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=shader,
  sharp corners,
  width=0.65\paperwidth,
  height=#1,
  nobeforeafter,
  valign=center,
  halign=center,
}

%%%

\offinterlineskip % <--------------

%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{sidebar}[0.15\paperheight]

    Top-Sidebar

\end{sidebar}
%
%
\begin{headbox}[0.15\paperheight]

    Headbox

\end{headbox}
%
%
\begin{sidebar}[0.85\paperheight]

    Bottom-Sidebar

\end{sidebar}
%
%
\begin{mainbox}[0.85\paperheight]

    Mainbox

\end{mainbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I've come to the point where I'm stuck with two things:

**Horizontal gaps between `tcolorbox` "tiles"**

When I'm trying to place two `tcolorbox` environments next to each other, there is a tiny, but still noticeable horizontal gap between the two colorboxes (encircled in red). I've already figured out that a well-placed `\offinterlineskip` does the job when trying to avoid vertical gaps between colorboxes placed directly above each other. Is there an equivalent command or argument that eliminates horizontal gaps between two `tcolorbox` environments that are placed side by side?

**Placing colorboxes in a pattern**

Technically the "Top-Sidebar" and "Bottom-Sidebar" should be a single colorbox. However, I seem to be unable to get place multiple `tcolorbox` environments next to each other without screwing up. Now, is there a way of "merging" the "Top-Sidebar" and "Bottom-Sidebar" in order to have the layout be the exact same pattern but with only one colorbox for each of the three colors?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: What happens when you also put a `%` directly after `\end{sidebar}`? (So you would have `\end{sidebar}%`)

Comment: That's it, thanks a whole lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Among other solutions, you could use a `\tcbposter` with three boxes. For `tcbposter` look at section 20 in `tcolorbox` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    paperheight=842pt,
    paperwidth=595pt,
    margin=0pt,
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{theme}{HTML}{333d4f}
\definecolor{shader}{HTML}{e3e4e6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {showframe, columns=1, rows = 1, spacing=0pt},
    boxes = {sharp corners, halign=center, valign=center, boxrule=0pt}
]
\posterbox[colback=theme]{name=sidebar, column=1, row=1, span=.35}{}
\posterbox[colback=shader, height=.15\paperheight]{name=headbox, column*=1, row=1, span=.65}{}
\posterbox[colback=white]{name=mainbox, column*=1, span=.65, below=headbox, rowspan=.85}{}
\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Amazing how compact the code is using `\tcbposter`.